# Dell shipped laptop start up scripts delllctservice delllctservicecontent starttracker

Tags: scripts, dell, startup, services

I have a M3800 Dell Laptop that came with Ubuntu pre-installed. The system usually stalls at shutdown, and I see an error about a starttracker pid not found. Maybe it is not relevant, and I am not looking here on how to resolve that error. 
But because of that, I noticed that there are two scripts that run at startup:
`/etc/init.d/delllctservice
/etc/init.d/delllctservicecontent`
which also starts
`/usr/bin/starttracker`

I have looked around in the internet to find out what these scripts and the services they start do), but I couldn't find anything about them, apart from this (unanswered, more than 1yr old) question on Dell forums, asking where can their source code be found (since they are GPLv3+):
http://en.community.dell.com/support-forums/software-os/f/3525/t/19643280

So, my questions are:
 1. What do these scripts do?
 2. Are they required for Ubuntu to run properly on Dell laptops?
 3. Where is the source code for them? Cause if we can't look at the source code, there is no way to know if Dell has a backdoor in our systems or not.

Comment: Scripts are usually text files, which is essentially source code. Why not look at them? Source code of compiled binaries is another matter, but compiled binaries aren't scripts.

Comment: I am looking at the scripts, and one of the two is starting a binaries as a service [/usr/bin/starttracker].

Comment: So what I want to know is what does that binary do? It doesn't seem to be part of the normal Ubuntu distro, so the only way to know is to either look at the source code, or trust someone's answer that he has already done so.
The other script, starts as a service, and checks a temporary file [/tmp/.delllct/delllctpipe] for commands to execute; based on the requested commands it will find in there, it starts some other scripts or binaries.